# How to grant a java tool write permission to /var/log?

Tags: permissions, java, logging

I'm running a java tool as a command line app using cronjob:
`java -jar /var/java/-myfile.jar`

By default I'm using `logback` and write to `/var/log/mylogfile.log`.

Problem: the user running the jar has no permissions to write to the `/var/log/` folder.
That folder has only permissions to `root syslog'.

Question: should I run the jar as `sudo`? Or should I give the running user write permissions to that folder? If yes, how?

Comment: Don't run the `.jar` as `sudo`; every mistake (wrong paths e.g.) could destroy your system. As `syslog` has write access, you might add the user to that group: `adduser <user> syslog`.

Comment: Thanks for you opinion. You might want to add this as an answer, so I could accept it lateron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I run the jar as sudo?

No. Far too dangerous since you could then change about anything to the system and a single misplaced space could remove your whole system.

> Or should I give the running user write permissions to that folder? If yes, how?

Yes.  The 2 main commands are to change write permissions and change the USER of your log file:

```
   sudo chmod 664 /var/log/{yourdir}/mylogfile.log
   sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/log/{yourdir}/mylogfile.log
```

where $USER is your current active user and {yourdir}/ is a directory you defined (mysql and apache for instance use their own directory in `/var/log/` instead of filling up `/var/log/`). It is a slightly better method.

Comment: Might be slightly better to actually create a directory within `/var/log` and change ownership of that directory as this allows the app to create or re-create the log file.

Comment: I agree :) editted.